# Android Image Banner with sliding feature

Tags: android, slider

Can anyone help me to get a simple library have the feature of sliding image banner with dot over the slider to show the image which is currently present. I have tried with ViewPager. Since I am new to Android, I am confused what to use. I tried many samples from GitHub, but I could make it run successfully. Can anyone give me a simple library for the same feature, horizontally sliding with image.

Answer (score 1):

There are loads of them and most of them works like they are meant to. So check [this](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) and [this](https://github.com/Cleveroad/SlidingTutorial-Android) out.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://github.com/Trinea/android-auto-scroll-view-pager) library!

But for dots you have to implement! what you can do is take a linearlayout at the bottom of the screen and add the dots dynamically based on number of images.

and if you want to have some animations while sliding of banners check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) link.